# How to write multiple .htaccess rewrite rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have multiple `php` pages like this:

```
http://www.example.com/si/article.php?id=122&nTitle=my-title
http://www.example.com/si/post.php?id=352&pTitle=my-post-title
```

i would like to rewrite them to

```
http://www.example.com/si/122/my-title
http://www.example.com/si/352/my-post-title
```

I tried different things in my `.htaccess` file and no result. Please tell me how to make to work with multiple rules. If I use one rule in `.htaccess` file its work for one php page like below:

```
RewriteRule ^([\s\w-]+)/(.*)/?$ article.php?id=$1&nTitle=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This is now I tried it for multiple pages:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Indexes
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
  RewriteRule ^/([\s\w-]+)/(.*)$ /article.php?id=$1&pName=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
  RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
  RewriteRule ^/([\s\w-]+)/(.*)$ /post.php?id=$1&pName=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Can anyone give me an advice on how to use this functionalities in `.htaccess`?

Thank you.

Comment: Both of those URLs have the same format - so how do you expect your rewriting to make the distinction, whether this is to be rewritten to `article.php` or `post.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use url like : (look like different from each other)

```
http://www.example.com/arical-si/122/my-title
http://www.example.com/post-si/352/my-post-title
```

then redirect to :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$0 
RewriteRule ^artical-si/([0-9+/=$]*)/([A-Za-z0-9+/=$]*)$ article.php?id=$1&nTitle=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^post-si/([0-9+/=$]*)/([A-Za-z0-9+/=$]*)$ post.php?id=$1&nTitle=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Now its working.. thanks. 
Can you tell me what this part says? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` Is it needed?

Comment: @user3733831 means that if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then procede to the rewrite rule below

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should test your regex, you can do it there [regex generator](https://regex101.com/)

Then in your htaccess, you can put your regex like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/post.php?id=([0-9])&pName=([a-z]+)$    post/$1/$2  [L]
RewriteRule ^/article.php?id=([0-9])&pName=([a-z]+)$    article/$1/$2  [L]
```

try it step by step and you can debug it easily.