# hide (remove) folder names in URL rewrite Rules Not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make clean URLs  removing folder names with htaccess and I have multiple folders (food, health,beauty .....) rewrite rules not working

```
       site.com/food/one.php

       TO

        site.com/one.php
```

**Rule for food folder**
RewriteEngine On

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /food/$1  [NC,L]

 </IfModule>
```

**Rule for health folder**

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /health/$1 [NC,L]
   
      </IfModule>
```

**Rule for beauty folder**

```
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /buety/$1 [NC,L]
   
      </IfModule>
```

**only one Rule works fine ( top rule only... whatever it may be ) rest of the rules not
working, getting internal server error 500**

Please Help me out

Comment: You can check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420087/how-to-write-multiple-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: Your three rules are identical in what they match, so the first one wins. They all say "regardless of what was typed, forward to the next folder", but there can only ever be one of those. You need to find a way, either in htaccess or PHP, to say "URLs such as _a_ should go to the food folder, and URLs such as _b_ should go to the health folder. The "such as" is your logic. It is harder to do in htaccess, so I'd recommend looking into PHP routing

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your rule blocks are one after the other in the root `.htaccess` file.

> rest of the rules not working, getting internal server error 500

Because you are unconditionally rewriting to the `/food/` subdirectory (because this rule is first) regardless of whether the target file exists or not. If it doesn't exist it will create a rewrite loop, which results in a 500 Internal Server Error response.

The remaining rules are only processed if the request already maps to a file (or directory), but then the preceding `RewriteCond` directives prevent the rule from doing anything (since it has already been established that the request maps to a file or directory).

If there is no discernable difference in the URL then you need to check that the target file exists before rewriting the request.

You can do this, but with the obvious caveat that you can't have the same filename in more than one subdirectory (the first will always "win"). We also need to make some assumptions...

1. You are rewriting requests for physical `.php` files only (as per your example).
2. `.php` is present in the URL (as per your example).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is already for one of the subdirectories then stop here
RewriteRule ^(food|health|beauty)($|/) - [L]

# If the request is for anything other than a ".php" file then stop here
RewriteRule !\.php$ - [L]

# If the request already maps to a file (or directory) then stop here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite to "/food" if the target file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/food/$0 -f
RewriteRule .+ food/$0 [L]

# Rewrite to "/health" if the target file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/health/$0 -f
RewriteRule .+ health/$0 [L]

# Rewrite to "/beauty" if the target file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/beauty/$0 -f
RewriteRule .+ beauty/$0 [L]
```

There is no need for the `<IfModule>` wrappers or the `RewriteBase` directive(s).

Although it does seem a bit odd that you would want to remove these subdirectories from the URL, as they look like "keywords" that would be better left in the URL?

Comment: getting 404 error (File not found)

Comment: @coder2022 What URL are you requesting? Where is the target file located?